# Finding a function for summation or product problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The positive integers which are less than or equal to 100 are written on a whiteboard. ${1,2,3,4,5,...,98,99,100}$.

Operation: Cross out any two numbers $x, y$, and write $xy+x+y$.

What is the last number that will be written?

I noticed that $xy+x+y=(x+1)(y+1)-1$

How can I derive a function to get the last number written ?

Comment: Looks you get $101!-1$ with your hint at the end

Comment: @ganeshie8 yes. but how to derive a function?

Comment: Ahh nice:) ok I just guessed it... 'll try to post a sol'n..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the given numbers on whiteboard represent the exponents in the prime factorization of a number $N$:

$$N={p_1}^1\cdot {p_2}^2\cdot  {p_3}^3\cdots {p_{100}}^{100}$$

Then the number of divisors of $N$ not including $1$ is given by 
$$(1+1)(2+1)(3+1)\cdots(100+1)-1 = 101!-1$$

Notice that it doesn't matter how you order or associate the prime powers.

---

For example, if you first pick two prime powers, say ${p_5}^5$ and ${p_9}^9$, then you strike these on your board and put $(5+1)(9+1)-1$.